# Laravel deploy: storage image doesn't work correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

After deploying my laravel project from local to Apache web server, all works correctly except images link. Here the code:

Images are stored in:

```
storage/app/public/photos
```

after i've run command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Images are linked at:

```
public/storage/photos
```

Controller:

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
   $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $file = $request->file('photo');
   $photo = $file->storeAs('public/photos', 'foto-' . time() . '.' . $extension);
   $user->photo = $photo;
   $user->save();
}
```

Images are uploaded correctly on storage/app/public/photos and correctly linked in public/storage/photos but it doesn't display on frontend.

in blade, i've tried to use Storage::url to retrieve the path

```
{{Storage::url($user->photo)}}
```

and asset()

```
{{asset($user->photo)}}
```

in both cases, image doesn't exist

The public path of image is:

```
http://mywebsite.com/storage/photos/foto-1522914164.png
```

Comment: What is exactly the value of $user->photo? Could you dump it?

Comment: "public/photos/foto-1522915528.png"

Comment: If you use asset function it will require that the value is "photos/foto-1522915528.png" (without public) otherwise it will be ``http://mywebsite.com/public/storage/photos/foto-1522914164.png``.

Comment: still not working, i think is configuration issue because in local machine everything is ok. Same code, online, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should Use **url** function to show your image like below way.

```
url($user->photo);
```

Comment: I my project , it's working fine.I think another problem of your code, Can you please check folder permission for your image folder.

Comment: folder permission are ok, the files has been stored correctly. The problem is only on frontend .

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change the controller code as follows:

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
  $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $file = $request->file('photo');
  $photoFileName = 'foto-' . time() . '.' . $extension;
  $photo = $file->storeAs('public/photos', $photoFileName);
  $user->photo = 'photos/' . $photoFileName;
  $user->save();
}
```

Then you can use `{{asset($user->photo)}}` in your blade.

Comment: in my opinion, i think there is a problem in deploy because on my local machine everything works correctly

Comment: What's the output of `{{asset($user->photo)}}` after uploading an image with this code?

Answer (score 0):

on my webspace, it seems that the only way to display image correctly is to create a custom route that read and serve the image.

i'm solved like this:

i'm storing only image name in db:

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
    $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = $request->file('photo');
    $photoFileName = 'photo-' . $model->id . '.-' . time() . '.' . $extension;
    $photo = $file->storeAs('public/photos', $photoFileName);
    $store = $photoFileName;
}
```

then, i've create custom route that read images and display them:

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}.{ext}', function ($filename, $ext) {
    $folders = glob(storage_path('app/public/*'), GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    $path = '';
    foreach ($folders as $folder) {
       $path = $folder . '/' . $filename . '.' . $ext;
       if (File::exists($path)) {
          break;
       }
    }

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', $type);

    return $response;
});
```

in blade, i'm using Storage to display image:

```
{{ Storage::url($photo->photo) }}}
```